# Can someone explain what does the interrupt "Trap" do in the micro controller

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, interrupt

I am using stm8l - discovery board and I am curious about the functionality of trap in the micro controller. My program stops instead of running continously in the while loop, Is the functionality of trap interrupt that if it occurs, it does not execute (similar to reset)?

```
#include <iostm8l.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


void Cus_delay(uint32_t ntime)
 {
   while(ntime!=0)
   {
    ntime--;
   }
 }  

main()
{
CLK_DIVR = 0x00; // Set the frequency to 16Mhz
PC_DDR = 0x80; // direction output for led
PC_CR1 = 0x80; // fast push pull mode
int a = 10;
while(1)
{
    Cus_delay(400000);
    Cus_delay(400000);
    PC_ODR ^= 0x80;
    a = a/0;
}
}
```

Comment: That `TRAP` was caused by the divide by `0` operation. It gives the programmer an opportunity to correct the result and attempt to resume execution. But often, it's a futile exercise, and it's easier to deal with the possible problem before the division occurs.

Comment: `trap` is a special interrupt which is being triggered by different erroneous situations defined by the specific architecture and is letting the code to gracefully handle these. In your case it's the division by zero.

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess this is more for the situation where there is some "kernel" and "user" code. So the kernel will handle it if user have screwed it up.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's possibly most useful in debugging, to identify where the problem occurred.

Comment: I used division by zero on purpose to check how the micro controller reacts for trap and the trap interrupt was set (after I read the conditional flags register), the program stops immediately after toggling the led (PC7). The software freezes and no action is taking palce

Comment: Because you don't have `trap` handler. Again, it is an interrupt, and interrupt should be handled.

Comment: @Viswa5095 There is probably a default handler in your runtime that you are expected to override.  It is most likely an infinite loop.  An alternative is to enable the hardware watchdog so that when the trap is entered, the processor will reset.  In other contexts, it is called an "exception".

Comment: sure I will look into it